# Where to find oil to extract with pump jack

Tags: rust

I've found an oil pump in an air drop w/ 10 survey charges. I know it follows similar mechanics as the mining quarry where you need to find a mineral rich area with the charges to actually place the device. However, I've used 8 of the 10 charges with no discovery of crude oil.  I've tried blasting sands, forested areas, even the alps but no oil. I'm just wondering, is there a particular biome that has a higher drop rate for it or is it completely randomized?

Comment: Pump jack has been removed :(

Comment: Was it removed recently?

Comment: Yeah last update which I think was a week ago

Comment: Will there be a new source of oil or will it just be granted by the RNG gods?

Comment: Not sure.  Check the devblog for an answer there I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arid Biomes...aka Dessert. Can also drio in Tundra I believe but the Dessert has a far better drop rate. Does not work on the beach as far as I am aware.